# Getting events from the scrollbar buttons?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, scrollbar

how can I access the arrow buttons on the ends of scrollbars in silverlight? Are they button controls which can be accessesed through thescrollbar class or something else?

The reason I need to know this is so that when someone click on either of the arrow buttons I can run some custom functionality to the scrollbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem like so:

```
foreach( var o in horizontalBar.GetVisualDescendants( ) )
            {
               if(o is RepeatButton)
               {
                     //set call back based on the name of the repeatbutton
                }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to know what button of the scrollbar was clicked you can could access that via the `ValueChanged` property of the `ScrollBar`

For instance I've got a simple scroll bar with a `textblock` and on each click, the `textblock` displays which button was clicked.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <ScrollBar Height="200" Orientation="Vertical" Width="20" ValueChanged="ScrollBar_ValueChanged" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,21,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

and the code behind would be

```
  private void ScrollBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue > e.OldValue)
                textBlock1.Text = "Down Arrow Clicked";
            else
                textBlock1.Text = "Up Arrow Clicked";
        }
```

Comment: What if someone drags the bar instead of clicks on the buttons?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. It works perfectly fine when a user drags the scroll bar too.